# How to align table in asp page?

Tags: html, css

I created simple asp page, Now my page look like this http://s7.postimg.org/fd9rw9ujv/Untitled_1_copy.png

I need to set table at center of the page, so i need to modify my only HTML and css.

I just confused due to code is contained with asp, I need something like this http://s21.postimg.org/ot42edul3/Invite.jpg

Html code:

But all the need html is included in above jsfiddle link.

Can anyone help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: try use **JQuery.dialog** [Dialog | JQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Comment: I strongly recommend remove table tag for login form.

Comment: thanks for your comments, i just need to use design of my table..

Comment: what's stopping you stylize JQ Dialog?

Comment: i cannot able to check with asp code, @ДмитрийЧистик: because my code is mixed with asp. thanks

Comment: @lv0gun9, any specific reason for that?

Comment: @rish It is maintenance problem.
1. Table tag is not designed for form design.
2. Table tag is not good for relative design.
Use div tag only not table. It is more suitable what your want. just an advice. no offence

Comment: Tables in a table in a table is never a good sign! As @lv0gun9 mentions it becomes a maintenance nightmare. Tables used for page layout were used when CSS was less standard across browsers. This is much less of a problem these days. You will end up with less HTML and more manageable code if you use CSS based designs instead.

Comment: @JonP ty. i'm not good to use English. you pointed right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the entire table up in a div with a class for styles. So on the first line of what you included in your JSFiddle

```
<div class="widthContainer">
```

and close the div on the last line

```
</div>
```

and center the content of that div with CSS

```
.widthContainer {
    width: 450px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

I made the width 450px because that is the width of your table as stated inline on your table tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/8tw43x89/

Some additional styles to get you started

```
.widthContainer {
    width: 450px;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.invitation-header {
    background-color: #eee;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

There was also a p tag that was pushing the width out

```
<p style="font-size: 11px; width: 565px;">
```

change that to

```
<p style="font-size: 11px;">
```

updated JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/97nk3tu3/

You'll want to sort out the padding in your table cells though

Comment: you can set the border in the .widthContainer CSS, check out http://jsfiddle.net/8tw43x89/1/

Comment: Made some additions based on your further questions but I should note that your question only really mentions the centering of your table

Comment: yes.. now only struggling with border for whole table.. i mean i need same as my posted image.. I think we will need to separate <td> for both header and next button... help me?.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use *div* tag  in it and try below code:

```
**<div style="text-align: center">**
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tblmain atep" style="width:450px; margin: 0 auto;"> 
 <tr>
        <td align="left" class="tdbodycontent">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="wrapper" style="width:450px;margin:0 auto;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="tdcontainer" align="left">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:450px;" id="tbl-two-columns">
                            <tr>
                                <th class="invitation-header" valign="top"> <!-- th added for invite header --selva -->
                        Help make your neighborhood safer, Invite friends and family
                                </th> <!-- END - th added for invite header --selva -->
                            </tr>
```

```
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id='tab1' class="tab-container" style="width:400px;">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top">

                                                <form method="post" name="form1" action="invitation_enrollv5.asp?action=1" onsubmit="return GetTextValue()">

                                                <!--START - Invite Buttons - Selvarani-->
                                                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin:0 auto 10px auto;width:350px;">
                                                <div id="main"><a style="float:right;" href="#" id="btAdd" value="" class="bt" />Invite more friends</a></div>

                                                <input type="hidden" id="contact_list" name="contact_list" value="" />
                                                <!--END - Invite Buttons - Selvarani-->
                                                </table>
                                                <p style="">Invite from my address book</p>
                                                <img src="Web5/images/invite-your-contacts.png" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="Invite your contacts" onclick="InviteBoxClick();" /><br />
                                                <a class="cs_import">
                                                </a>

                                                </form>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id='tab2' class="tab-container">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td valign="top">
                                                <form id="form2" name="form1" method="post" action="invitation_enrollv5.asp?action=4">
                                                <p>
                                                    Your invitations automatically include a message about AlertID, but it is always
                                                    more personal and effective if you include a short invitation note. You may edit
                                                    or remove the default copy below.<br />
                                                    <textarea name="cnote" id="cnote" cols="48" rows="7"></textarea>
                                                </p>
                                                <br />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="contact_list" value="" />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="pkfamilyinvite" value="" />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="fincomplete" value="" />
                                                <input type="hidden" name="vn" value="" />
                                                  <input type="hidden" name="gORn" value="" />
                                                <p>
                                                    Send a preview to yourself to check your invitation(s) before sending to others.<br />
                                                    <input type="submit" value="Send Preview to My Email" name="submit2" title="send preview to " />
                                                <br />
                                                <p>
                                                    Click below to send your invitations now.<br />
                                                    <input type="submit" value="Send Invitations" name="submit2" />
                                                </p>
                                                <br />
                                                <p style="font-size: 11px; width: 565px;">
                                                    By using this invitation system, I certify that the email addresses I entered above
                                                    are of persons I know and for whom I have a pre-existing relationship. I am not
                                                    sending invitations to individuals I do not personally know or do not have some
                                                    relationship to me or my group. You are limited to approximately 150 email addresses
                                                    here. If you have more than that, please contact support who will gladly help you.
                                                    <a href="mailto:community-1@alerts.alertid.com">community-1@alerts.alertid.com.</a></p>
                                                <br />
                                                <input name="submit2" type="submit" value="<< Back - To Contacts" />
                                                </form>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" class="tdfooter">
                        <div class="wrapper">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: I have just added extra "div" tag and apply style to it(<div style="text-align: center">). All other code is same as above